# Cannot Create Virtualenv on Android

Tags: android, python, virtualenv

I just installed Python2.7 on my Android tablet using [BotBrew](http://botbrew.inportb.com/). Python works fine, and I was able to install Setuptools via egg, and install Pip via setuptools. Pip is working well and I was able to pip install yolk and Django. They seem to be working fine, so I think the base Python setup is good.

I was able to pip install virtualenv, but the problem starts when I try to create a new virtual environment. The error I get is:

```
ERROR: The executable venv/bin/python could not be run: [Errno 13] Permission denied.
```

When I look into venv/bin/ the only file created is "python", not all of the others that would typically be in that dir. I get permission denied when I try to run that python file, even after I manually do a chmod +x on it.

I am trying to create the virtualenv on my SD card which is FAT32. I suspect that symlinks are not working due to the filesystem format.

I found [this possibly-related bug against Virtualenv on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/virtualenv/+bug/442780).

Can anyone suggest a way around this problem?